# How to check if a file exists without looking at its extension name in Python?

Tags: python

A file can have multiple extensions but name of the file will remains same. 
I have tried

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile("Filename")
```

but this code is looking at the extension of the file also.

Comment: import glob
glob.glob('Filename.*')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would list all files with same name but different extensions.

```
import glob
print glob.glob("E:\\Logs\\Filename.*")
```

You could use this check instead.

```
import glob
if glob.glob("E:\\Logs\\Filename.*"):
    print "Found"
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory/3215392#3215392) post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
import os

def check_file(dir, prefix):
    for s in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.splitext(s)[0] == prefix and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, s)):
            return True

    return False
```

You can call this function like, e.g., `check_file("/path/to/dir", "my_file")` to search for files of the form `/path/to/dir/my_file.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fnmatch` also,

```
import os
import fnmatch

print filter(lambda f: fnmatch.fnmatch(f, "Filename.*"), os.listdir(FilePath))
```

Here, No need to format `FilePath`. You can simply write like '`C:\Python27\python.*`'

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the files with the basename you want (in this case 'tmp') with or without an extension and will exclude things that start with your basename - like tmp_tmp.txt for example:

```
import re
import os

basename='tmp'
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  if re.match(basename+"(\..*)?$", filename):
     print("this file: %s matches my basename"%filename)
```

Or of course if you prefer them in a list, more succinctly:

```
[fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if re.match(basename+"(\..*)?$",fn)]
```